# How PHP full text search works or not really, boolean mode

Tags: php, full-text-search

I would like to ask more info about PHP ?BOOLEAN? fulltext search.

```
$searchquery=mysqli_query($dbconnect,"select *, MATCH(s.title,s.url, s.keyword, s.`desc`) AGAINST('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE )  AS score from site s where MATCH(s.title, s.keyword, s.url, s.`desc`) AGAINST('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE ).
```

Sample keywords, some China and Arabic and normal Europe

(Arabic works)السيارات
中国的房子 (not working)
Tädiauto (works) Tädid (doesn't work)
all without äõü'ss etc works(english) ()
Someone can explain me this

at the end I set my tables to  utf8_general_ci, nothing changed.
I use `$keywords=htmlspecialchars($keywords, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");`

It makes me feel that not all words are searchable words with full text search?

---

anyways because like (%keyword%) works there is no issue with the database, or is the match() against() a Mysql separate search program that needs something, this seems to be so random search engine. Nobody seems to know this, how Google does it, need to investigate this.

Comment: You mean MySQL Fulltext search

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: Thank you, but would like more specific information, as I read all that, it makes me feel like * , How do I enter command or modify the code, or the database to remove these errors that make no sense? I am not professional handling PHP my admin, I don't know every corner of that program. Maybe someone can help me without this chaos. starting from PHP code. etc

Comment: I don't have any clue how to set --innodb_ft_max_token_size=# or something like that, and if it's even the right direction here. Please help me out here..reading 10 times the mySQL manual isn't efficient at all.

Comment: Maybe i can change some settings like disabling words stop list from PHP my admin panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was searching a lot, never seen this suggestion, PHP:

`mysqli_set_charset($dbconnect, 'utf8');
mysqli_query($dbconnect, "SET NAMES 'utf8';");
mysqli_query($dbconnect, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';");
mysqli_query($dbconnect, "SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci';");`